# Testing secure server with pem certficiate in dart/flutter

Tags: dart, security, https, pem

I am trying to test a secure server/client request in dart, using a pem certificate. I have setup the server with the pem as context, and the client using the same, but I always get "connection terminated during handshake". Would anyone have any advice as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
test('certs', () async {

SecurityContext context = SecurityContext();
var fullChain = Platform.script.resolve('lib/certs/cert.pem').toFilePath();

context.useCertificateChain(fullChain);

HttpServer
    .bindSecure(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 443, context)
    .then((server) {
      print('server running');
  server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
    request.response.write('Hello, world!');
    request.response.close();
  });
});

HttpClient p = HttpClient(context: context)
  ..badCertificateCallback = (cert, host, port) {
      return fullChain == cert.pem;
  };

var request = await p.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://127.0.0.1:443')).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
var response = await request.close();
```

});

Comment: Got it working - I wasn't using the key for the server security context!